# What is use of | (bitwise or operator ) in the context of setiosflags?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    cout << setiosflags(ios::left |  ios::showpos) << 45 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know bitwise operator are used with int number to manipulate bit. But here it seems that it is working like do the both job , I mean ios::left then do the ios::showpos part .But I am not understanding the use of | operator here.Can anyone explain me why | was used here to do such kind of work

Comment: Read up on bit masking and see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags.

Comment: On a side note, this code can be rewritten using [I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) instead: `std::cout << std::left << std::showpos << 45 << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise `or` operator can be used to "bitwise combine" values, example the result of: `0010 | 0001` will be: `0011` see the 2 bits that were set to true are both set to true in the result.

And bitwise `and` can be used to check an value if a particular bit is set.

Check this simpler example:

```
enum FlagValues
{
    //note: the values here need to be powers of 2
    FirstOption  = 1,
    SecondOption = 2,
    ThirdOption  = 4,
    ForthOption  = 8
};
void foo(int bitFlag)
{
    //check the bitFlag option with binary and operator
    if(bitFlag & FirstOption)
        std::cout << "First option selected\n";
    if(bitFlag & SecondOption)
        std::cout << "Second option selected\n";
    if(bitFlag & ThirdOption)
        std::cout << "Third option selected\n";
    //...
}

int main()
{
    //note: set the bits into a bit flag with
    int bitFlag = 0;
    bitFlag |= FirstOption; // add FirstOption into bitFlag 
    bitFlag |= ThirdOption; // add ThirdOption into bitFlag
    std::cout << "bitFlagValue is: " << bitFlag << '\n';

    //call foo with FirstOption and the ThirdOption
    foo(bitFlag);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All ios flags are simply coded as separate bits in a implementation defined order. That makes it possible to add flags by simply do a bitwise or with them.

If you look in the gcc header file `bits/ios_base.h` you will find the following definition:

```
enum _Ios_Fmtflags
{
    _S_boolalpha  = 1L << 0,
    _S_dec        = 1L << 1,
    _S_fixed      = 1L << 2,
    _S_hex        = 1L << 3,
    _S_internal   = 1L << 4,
    _S_left       = 1L << 5,
    _S_oct        = 1L << 6,
    _S_right      = 1L << 7,
    _S_scientific     = 1L << 8,
    _S_showbase   = 1L << 9,
    _S_showpoint  = 1L << 10,
    _S_showpos    = 1L << 11,
    _S_skipws     = 1L << 12,
    _S_unitbuf    = 1L << 13,
    _S_uppercase  = 1L << 14,
    _S_adjustfield    = _S_left | _S_right | _S_internal,
    _S_basefield  = _S_dec | _S_oct | _S_hex,
    _S_floatfield     = _S_scientific | _S_fixed,
    _S_ios_fmtflags_end = 1L << 16,
    _S_ios_fmtflags_max = __INT_MAX__,
    _S_ios_fmtflags_min = ~__INT_MAX__
};
```

and some lines later:

```
 ....

/// Generates a decimal-point character unconditionally in generated
/// floating-point output.
static const fmtflags showpoint =   _S_showpoint;

/// Generates a + sign in non-negative generated numeric output.
static const fmtflags showpos =     _S_showpos;

/// Skips leading white space before certain input operations.
static const fmtflags skipws =      _S_skipws;

....
```

As you can see, every flag is represented as a single specific bit. That makes it easy to "add" them together by using or.